# How to debug iOS assert failure crash when it leaves no stack

Tags: ios, crash, assert, assertion, symbolicate

I am trying to debug what appears to be an assertion failure on iOS. The device in question seems to produce no crash logs. Instead, in the console, I see this:

```
Apr 11 16:22:56 iPhone5 SpringBoard[69] <Warning>: Killing com.yourapp for termination assertion
Apr 11 16:22:56 iPhone5 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.appspot.scruffapp[0xa993][19484]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.yourapp[0xa993]) Exited: Killed: 9
```

Is there any way to connect this very limited information to an actual source file + line number? Also, why might the device not be creating any crash logs, which are obviously much easier to symbolicate and diagnose?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Is this a crash you can reproduce at will?  Have you tried debugging with a breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not seem to be able to reproduce this crash at will; my colleague hit it and I attached his phone to my machine and this was all I could get. I have not been successful repoing the crash in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
@try {
    //code here
}
@catch (NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea; I don't know where to place this code unfortunately giving the failure of iOS to provide a stack in either the console or a separate log file.

Comment: Step through it using breakpoints to locate where it is crashing.  Or is it not building?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot repro this crash on demand and have been unable to see it happen in the debugger. I was hoping I could symbolicate (somehow) with the output from the console.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood.  I've not used this method, but given the amount of upvotes it has, people seem to have found this answer very useful with regards to symbolicating iPhone crash reports:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/1710611 - Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I myself have used that method with success. Unfortunately, for whatever reason there is no crash file for me to symbolicate, just these cryptic lines from the device console (viewable via the organizer).